# If value matches in Column then return the row

Tags: excel

I have two Excel files A and B each having 4 columns x 5000 rows, which I am using for an audit.

File A has these 5000 rows -

```
Column A - Account Numbers

Column B - Customer Name

Column C - Limit Sanctioned 

Column D - Outstanding
```

File B has these rows -

```
Column A - Account Numbers

Column B - Type of Facility

Column C - Date of Sanction

Column D - Rate of Interest
```

I want to match the Account Numbers (from File A to File B), If Account Number matches then I should return the full row from File B. Is it possible?

as e.g.

Take Account Number from Column A (File A) and match with the full column A of File B, If Account Number exist. Then return the full Row from that Column of File B.

I am trying with the `VLOOKUP ( VALUE, RANGE, INDEX NO.,MATCH)`

I took account number as `VLOOKUP ('55400055444, A1:A5000,1,FALSE)` giving me one cell only. Not the full row, how can I get the full matched row records?

Comment: you would need to put that formula in for each cell you want to pull over increasing the 1 (which should really be 2) by 1 for each column you move to the right. If you want to manually change the order of the columns, then simply change the 1 to a 4 or a 2 to suite your needs.  1 pulls the column you are looking in.  2 would be the next column, 3 the one after that and so on.  make sure the number you use where you have the one is not greater than the number of columns in your look up range.

Comment: I have more than 5000 rows x 4 columns, means 20000 cells, will not be possible to put in all of them.. any idea please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would suggest, is have both books open at the same time as it will make your cell addressing a bit easier and less prone to typos.

In column E adjacent in your first row of data, lets assume its row 2, you would use a formula like:

```
VLOOKUP ($A2, 'filname/sheetname'!$A$2:$D$5000,column(B$1),0)
```

When you are selecting A2 that is the current workbook you are in.  When you select the lookup range, that will be the other workbook.  Because you have it open, it will fill in th proper filename format.  You can add the $ by pressing F4 right after you select the range, or you can add them in afterwards.  Column(B$1) is just a way to count and references the work book where your formula is.  once the formula looks right, copy it to the right as far as you need...3 rows.  Then select all the rows with the formula and copy down.

When you perform the copy paste operation, cell addresses without the $ will adjust automatically.  the cell references with the $ will be locked and wont change.

Comment: `'filname/sheetname'!$A$2:$A$5000` will need to include more than one column or `column(B$1)` will cause an error looking for the second column in a single column set.

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner, I was thinking about that and meant to type that in in the first place, I just edited it now.